# how to reduce the retry count of AXIS2-1.3 for failure scenario?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am using axis2.1.3 with JDK1.6,

When I am invoking the client, it is sending the request 3 times.

By querying in Google, I found that its default value is 3.

How to reset it to 1 or 0, because for failure transaction it is sending 3 times.

Presently I am using the bellow code, but it is not working.

```
ServiceClient sc = null;
sc = clientStub._getServiceClient();    
DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler retryHandler = new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(0, false);
sc.getOptions().setProperty(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, retryHandler);
```

Can you please help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks,
Satyapriya sahoo